# calculus questions monotonic decreasing function

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve this:
if $f(x)$ monotonic decreasing , and $limf(x)=0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty $ in the set $I=[0,\infty)$.

What I know by definition is that:

1. To every $x_1,x_2\in I $ $x_1<x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1)>f(x_2)$
2. To every $ \epsilon>0 $ exists $M>0$ so every $x\in I$ follows $ |f(x)-0|=|f(x)|<\epsilon$

   I need to prove that $f(x)>0$ to every $x\in I$ ...I understand it intuitavly, but can't get how to prove it. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What would happen if there was a $x \in I$ such that $f(x) \leq 0$?

Comment: @posilon It'd have contradiction with the monotonic decreasing function... so you trying to say to try to proove it with contradiction?

Comment: Yes, I was suggesting to prove it with contradiction. There would be a contradiction, but that doesn't follow just from the fact that $f(x)$ is decreasing. For example $f(x)=-x$ is decreasing but $f(1)<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(a)<0 \text{ for some } a$ from this it follows that $f(x)<f(a)<0 \text{ for all } x>a$.

Therefore your second point that $ |f(x)|< \epsilon $ fails for when $\epsilon<|f(a)|$
This leads to a contradiction and shows $f(a)<0$ can't be true

Comment: how did you come to $\epsilon<|f(a)|$ ?

Comment: if $f(a)<0 $ then $|f(a)|>0$ by definition. but also $\epsilon>0$, so you are saying that there's must be a case when $f(a)<\epsilon$

Comment: $|f(x)| > |f(a)|$ for all $x>a$ If $|f(a)| > \epsilon$ it follows that $|f(x)|>\epsilon$

Comment: @Michal: You should also show that $f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x \in I$. This can be easily reduced to your argument: Say that $f(b)=0$ for some $b \in I$. Choose any $a \in (b,+\infty)$. Then $f(a)<f(b)=0$ and you can continue with your argument.